# java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Tags: java, firebase, collections

I want to read a map `map` from the Database (Firebase),and i compare it to another map `motcle`, if i find a duplicate key i increment the value of the key in `map`,I am having a ClassCastException.
the code:

```
public void addMotcle(final Map motcle, String Userid)
{
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User");
    DatabaseReference user = mDatabase.child(Userid);
    final DatabaseReference keylist = user.child("motcle");
    keylist.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists())
            {   
                //I tried to put the map in another map and change it but 
                //It is still the same error
                Map<String,Integer> map = (Map) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                Map<String,Integer>Hmap= new HashMap<>();
                Hmap.putAll(map);
                //if there is duplicate we incremente les mots clé
                for (Object key : motcle.keySet()) {
                    if (Hmap.containsKey(key)) {
                        Hmap.put((String)key,((Integer) Hmap.get(key))+1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Hmap.put((String) key,1);
                    }
                }
               keylist.setValue(Hmap);

            }
            else
            {
             keylist.setValue(motcle);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });



}
```

Here is the Value that i want to write on in Firebase [image: Data]

the error is in the line  `map.put((String)key,map.get(key)+1);`

why can't i write an `Integer` in the value if i declared `map` as  `Map<String,Integer>` ?

Comment: You are dealing with Integer wrapper class, not with primitive int, hence it doesn't do it. Do type casting and then again `new Integer(result_int)`

Comment: can you try `map.put((String) key, ((Integer) map.get(key)) + 1);`

Comment: I don't know Firebase, but a quick look in the documentation seems to suggest that your assumption about the return value of `dataSnapshot.getValue()` is wrong. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#getValue() According to that link, the method will never return a `Map<String,Integer>`, nor will it ever return `Integer`.

Comment: even when doing `map.put((String)key,((Integer) map.get(key))+1);` it is the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `Map<String,Integer> map = (Map) dataSnapshot.getValue();`, you guarantee that `map` is a `Map`, but not that it's a `Map<String, Integer>`. Since generics are erased and not available at runtime, as long as `dataSnapshot.getValue()` is a `Map` of some kind, this cast will succeed.

Because you've declared `Hmap` as a `Map<String,Integer>`, when you get a value from the map, it will try to cast it to `Integer`, but there is nothing *actually guaranteeing ahead-of-time that it will be an Integer*. As a result, if the value is actually a `Long`, it will try to cast that `Long` to an `Integer` and fail (because `Long` does not extend `Integer`, and widening operations don't work on boxed types).

You need to find out what the actual types of the values of `dataSnapshot.getValue()` are, and cast it to the correct type of `Map` to avoid this error.

See here for more details: [Weird problem about Java Generics operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041670/weird-problem-about-java-generics-operation)

Comment: the actual types of the values of `dataSnapshot.getValue` is `Map<String,Integer>` that's why i put it in a map with a `<String,Integer>`

Comment: @Anis Kaloun How do you know that that is the type? What is the result of `map.get(key).getClass()`?

Comment: I didn't i am going to try it now, so if i write in the database a `Map<String,Integer>` with `setValue` and after i want to read it , it doesn't guarante to still be a `Map<String,Integer>`?

Answer (score -1):

That is because keylist is a final variable you can’t change its value so you can just initialize it like that:-

```
DatabaseReference keylist = user.child("motcle");
```

Comment: I tried to create another Map and copy the content but it is still the same error  `Map<String,Integer> map = (Map) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                    Map<String,Integer>Hmap= new HashMap<>();
                    Hmap.putAll(map);
                    //if there is duplicate we incremente les mots clé
                    for (Object key : motcle.keySet()) {
                        if (Hmap.containsKey(key)) {
                            Hmap.put((String)key,((Integer) Hmap.get(key))+1);
                        }`

Comment: A variable being `final` does not preclude performing mutating operations on the variable. It only stops you from reassigning the variable to reference a different object.